# comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep8

```
while line_number < dictionary_elements_number and validation_bool == False:
```

getting this error when i run it throught pep8 `E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'`

isn't that a bit weird?

Comment: Did you read the error message at all?

Comment: "Isn't that a bit weird?" No.

Comment: Either use:    `while line_number < dictionary_elements_number and not validation_bool:` or   `while line_number < dictionary_elements_number and validation_bool is False:`

Comment: i know how to fix it i just don't understand why i'm getting it.

Comment: It is considered poor programming practice in Python to use an equivalence comparison to `False` as a `True` value in a statement.  It can be confusing to future people looking at your code.

Comment: @Clara Look at the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) documentation:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or
>   is not, never the equality operators.

I guess False is also a [singleton](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/singleton).

Answer (score 0):

while line_number < dictionary_elements_number and validation_bool is False:

Comment: This seems to recommend the same solution as the existing accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48522050/7733418 , just less explained (i.e. not at all). Please [edit] to make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute.